# Using AutofitTextView with Button

Tags: android, xml, android-widget

I'm using the AutofitTextView in my app and it works fine with a TextView widget, but I can't get it to work with a Button.  I've tried by adding the xml to the Button xml.

I want the Text to re-size with the Button.

Below is my code:

```
  <Button
     android:id="@+id/showAnswerButton"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_weight="7"
     android:background="#000000"
     android:text="Show Answer" >

   <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/libs/me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView"
    android:id="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textSize="50sp" />     
    </Button>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Button is not a groupView so you cannot add another view inside a button view

Comment: You cannot place the `AutofitTextView` within the `Button`. You'll need to remove the `</Button>` and end the button tag before starting the `AutofitTextView`

Answer (score 0):

Good news! Google introduced Auto fit textview support in Android O. It will be also included in support libraries.

[Click Here](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/autosizing-textview.html)